# How to get model from mlflow from run_id

Tags: python, mlflow

I'm trying to retrieve my pytorch model saved in mlflow Model Registry but fail in figuring out how to do so exactly. I managed to get the run_id by filtering all experiments for experiment_name, then sorting by my preferred metric, and taking the run_id of the first in the resulting dataframe.

However, I am now stopped. In the mlflow documentation I cannot find any convenient function to help me transitioning from run_id (which should be unique and specific to a single model run with specific set of arguments and parameters) to model object. I'm aware of `mlflow.pytorch.load_model()` that can accept run URI too, but I don't understand why I need to pass the "run-relative/path/to/artifact" separately to the `runs:/<run_id>`; furthermore, how to get that correct run URI exactly.

My current code is the following:

```
import mlflow

def get_best_run_id(experiment_name, metric_to_sort_by='f1_score'):
  
    experiments = mlflow.list_experiments()
    experiment_path = [exp.name for exp in experiments if experiment_name in exp.name][0]
    
    experiment_dict = dict(mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_path))
    
    experiment_id = experiment_dict['experiment_id']
    runs_df = mlflow.search_runs(experiment_id)
  
    runs_df_filtered = runs_df[runs_df['status'] == 'FINISHED'][[col for col in runs_df.columns if col.startswith('params.') or col.startswith('metrics.')]].dropna()
    runs_df_indices = runs_df_filtered.sort_values(f"metrics.{metric_to_sort_by}", ascending=False).index
    
    runs_df = runs_df.loc[runs_df_indices, :]  
    best_run_id = runs_df['run_id'].tolist()[0]
    
    return best_run_id
  
best_run_id = get_best_run_id("<my_experiment_name>") 
mlflow.pytorch.load_model(f"runs:/{best_run_id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you logged your model. There are several ways to define the `model_uri`. As the [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pytorch.html) shows:

```
# Log the model
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, "model")

# Inference after loading the logged model
model_uri = "runs:/{}/model".format(run.info.run_id)
loaded_model = mlflow.pytorch.load_model(model_uri)
```

The code logs the model as "model". Then, when loading the model, it inserts "model" in the URI. Your code doesn't show how you logged the model before. Maybe, you should get back to it and edit it.